# Regime-switching regression

Tags: regression, time-series, change-point

I know that dependence of $x$ and $y$ in my time series data changes in time. Suppose we have monthly time series from 1990 to 2011. If we independently regress $x$ and $y$ for 1990 to 2000 and from 2000 to 2011, the results are quite different. There is low dependence in the former sample and strong in the latter. Although I approximately know the moment of structural shift, I wish to have a statistical model, which allows reveal this moment more precisely.
I know about regime-switching regression models, but they only provide different parameters and do not test the moment of structural shift.
Is there any regime-switching regression model for time series, which helps to identify the moment of time, when switch happens?
I know about markov-switching autoregression models (MSVAR), but in my problem I need to apply simple regression without autoregression terms. Are there other more simple and suitable approaches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When testing for structural changes, should a linear trend be identified from the data or the derivative of data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280019/when-testing-for-structural-changes-should-a-linear-trend-be-identified-from-th)