# When testing for structural changes, should a linear trend be identified from the data or the derivative of data?

Tags: r, change-point, structural-change

There exists a linear trend in an otherwise non-linear set of time-series data. The linear trend can be identified using a change-point (or breakpoint for structural changes) analysis method. This method detects a change in the structure of a series. The structure is a linear regression model. However, the identified breakpoints are different if the analysis method is used on the data or the derivative of the data. I am concerned about which to use.

I have also created a sample set of data in R to explain what I am talking about. The real changepoints are set as 103 and 127. Breakpoint analysis is done using the 'strucchange' package. The analysis on the data finds breakpoints 97 and 173. The analysis on the derivative (over 61 points to smooth) returns breakpoints 87 and 178. Is there an accepted way to find the linear region using a structural analysis method? Why is there a difference between the breakpoints when evaluating the data set versus the derivative?

[image]

```
#### Setting seed and initiliazing package
sets <- 10
library(strucchange)

#### Creating noisy second order data
x2 <- seq(1,200)
set.seed(sets)
ord2 <- x2^2 + rnorm(n = length(x2), mean = 0, sd = 500)

#### Creating a split in the parabola
set.seed(sets)
linSplit <- 102
x2[seq(linSplit+1,length(x2))] <- x2[seq(linSplit+1,length(x2))] + 25

#### Creating noisy linear data
slope <- diff(c(linSplit,(linSplit+1))^2)
int <- ord2[linSplit] - slope*linSplit
x1 <- seq((linSplit+1),(linSplit+25))
set.seed(sets)
ord1 <- x1*slope + rnorm(n = length(x1), mean = 0, sd = 500) + int

#### Combining 1st and 2nd order data
ord2[seq(linSplit+1,length(x2))] <- ord2[seq(linSplit+1,length(x2))] + ord1[length(ord1)] - ord1[1]
yAll <- c(ord2[1:linSplit], drop, ord1, ord2[seq(linSplit+1,length(ord2))])
xAll <- sort(c(x2,xDrop,x1))

#### Plotting data and derivative 
plot(xAll, yAll, xlim = c(0,226))
cps <- breakpoints(ts(yAll) ~ 1, h = 0.1, breaks = 2)$breakpoints
abline(v = cps, lty = 2, col = "green")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(seq(31, (length(xAll)-31)), diff(yAll, 61),pch = 8, col = "blue", axes = FALSE, xlab = NA, ylab = NA,
     xlim = c(0,226))
cpsDer <- breakpoints(ts(diff(yAll, 26)) ~ 1, h = 0.1, breaks = 2)$breakpoints
abline(v = seq(31, (length(xAll)-31))[cpsDer], lty = 4, col ="red")
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the analysis because `drop` and `xDrop` are not available. However, from the description alone it seems to be wrong to fit a constant-only model (`~ 1`). If you want to detect changes in the slopes of regressors, do include the regressors in your `breakpoints()` application. The `strucchange` package as well as the accompanying papers also provide examples for this situation.

Comment: @AchimZileis Thank you, this is what turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's an issue more related to the test than the series itself, and apart from the hypothesis the test requires, I see no obvious reason why you should use the differentiated series. In the specific case of the `R` package `strucchange`, the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/strucchange.pdf) [p. 11] states that:

> All procedures in this package are concerned with testing or assessing deviations from stability in the classical linear regression model.

which suggests you should observe whether the model you're using for the data prior to using the `breakpoints` functions satisfies the hypothesis related to linear regressions.

From your example, if you have reason to believe the series contains a deterministic trend, it seems more coherent to account for this characteristic in the model than simply differentiating the series, which I guess would be overdifferencing.

Comment: A nice and easy to read discussion on overdifferencing [economics context] is in this text from John Cochrane: https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/overdifferencing.pdf